# nginx under supervisor can't open conf file

Tags: nginx, supervisord, selinux, rhel7

This is very puzzling:

I'm on RHEL 7.5, trying to run Nginx 1.14.0 under Supervisor 3.3.4.  The ultimate aim is to serve a Django site.

My "/etc/init.d/supervisord" looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
...
# Source init functions
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

prog="supervisord"
prog_bin="/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf"
PIDFILE="/var/run/$prog.pid"

start()
{
   echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
   daemon $prog_bin --pidfile $PIDFILE
   sleep 1
   [ -f $PIDFILE ] && success $"$prog startup" || failure $"$prog startup"
   echo
}
... # "stop", "restart" functions, etc.
```

"/etc/supervisord.conf" looks like this:

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/var/run//supervisor.sock 

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = 
supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///var/run//supervisor.sock

[include]
files = /etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf
```

"/etc/supervisor/conf.d/" has just one file in it: nginx.conf:

```
[program:nginx]
user=root
command=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /path/to/site/etc/nginx.conf
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=3
redirect_stderr=True
```

Invoking the above command directly with `sudo /usr/sbin/nginx -c /path/to/site/etc/nginx.conf &` is successful. It starts right up and I can see the nginx processes with `ps -ef`

But if I start supervisor d like this:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/supervisord restart
```

It fails to launch Nginx:

```
$ sudo cat /var/log/supervisor/nginx-stdout---supervisor-tqI97D.log
nginx: [emerg] open() "/path/to/site/etc/nginx.conf" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

Permissions to read that file are good all the way down. Of course, the path is not *actually* called "/path/to/site/etc/nginx.conf", but there's an "x" for all users on every directory and a "r" for all users on the conf file itself:

```
$ namei -om /path/to/site/etc/nginx.conf
f: /path/to/site/etc/nginx.conf
 dr-xr-xr-x root    root   /
 drwxr-xr-x root    root   path
 drwxr-xr-x root    root   to
 drwxrwxr-x user1   group1 site
 drwxrwxr-x user1   group1 etc
 -rw-r--r-- root    group1 nginx.conf
```

How can there be an error on an "open()" operation for this file?  I've tried changing the "user" to root in "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/nginx.conf" and/or in "/etc/supervisord.conf" but the result is always the same.

Could the fact that this is SELinux make a difference? It's currently activated.

```
$ getenforce
Enforcing
```

If it helps, the nginx.conf file that can't be opened looks like this:

```
user  nginx;
daemon off;

error_log  /path/to/site/var/log/nginx-error.log warn;
pid        /path/to/site/var/run/nginx.pid;

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /path/to/site/var/log/nginx-access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    upstream app_server {
        server unix:/path/to/site/var/run/my-django.socket fail_timeout=0;
    }

    server {
        listen 8000;
        server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
        charset utf-8;

        location /media  {
            alias /path/to/site/htdocs/media;
        }

        location /static {
            alias /path/to/site/htdocs/static;
        }

        location / {
            uwsgi_pass  app_server;
            include     /path/to/site/etc/uwsgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you maybe test run using 'root' as user in your nginx.conf see if it does anything more? Of course and im sure you know, running programs as root are never a solution and is extremely dangerous - i felt i needed to warn future readers about this, we all did crazy things when we started fiddling with computers, right. hehe

Comment: Also, you could try setenforce 0 to help eliminate the selinux potential fault, this is only a temporary measure and will not persist

Comment: Are there any relevant log entries in audit log (`/var/log/audit/audit.log`)?

Comment: @OldFart - Yes! Setting setenforce 0 enables it to work! So the issue is with SELinux and not in the supervisor config.  I also noticed that moving the nginx config file from `/path/to/site/etc/nginx.conf` to simply `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` allows it to run even with SELinux enforcement in place. Does SELinux have rules about where in the filesystem it can and can't read from?

Comment: @sebasth When I try to start Nginx from supervisorctl, the first line to "audit.log" is "type=AVC msg=audit(1536945269.368:22963): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=1605 comm="nginx" name="nginx.conf" dev="dm-0" ino=102588286 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:default_t:s0 tclass=file"
- Can this help me find a way to allow the Nginx user to read that file?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check with [SELinux](https://selinuxproject.org) to really grasp the whole concept before doing anything to a production machine.

> The httpd_t context permits NGINX to listen on common web server ports, to access configuration files in /etc/nginx, and to access content in the standard docroot location (/usr/share/nginx). It does not permit many other operations, such as proxying to upstream locations or communicating with other processes through sockets.

Once you are a king at SELinux (hah) check out [NGINX's - Modifying SELinux Settings](https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-nginx-plus-with-selinux/)

Let us know, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

On SELinux enabled systems process and files have security labels. SELinux policy contains the allowed access patterns between these labels. Access is denied if there is not a rule allowing the access.

The security labels on your nginx files seem to be incorrect: the AVC error message tells that access was denied for a process in `httpd_t` domain trying to access a file with `default_t` label. To allow access, you need to assign suitable security contexts  to your nginx files. Possible contexts are documented in  [*httpd_selinux* man page](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/8-httpd_selinux/). For configuration files, an approriate context would be `httpd_config_t` and for user content perhaps `httpd_user_content_t`.

You can manually apply a new security context to a file using `chcon` tool. After you have decided the security contexts to use, you should save them in file context database using `semanage`. Otherwise automatic relabeling will label the files incorrectly.

I've written a more detailed answer on the topic on related Unix & Linux Stack exchange question [*Configure SELinux to allow daemons to use files in non-default locations*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/392833/configure-selinux-to-allow-daemons-to-use-files-in-non-default-locations).

Comment: I eventually solved my problem by tailing `/var/log/audit/audit.log` and recording the error that appeared there when I tried to start Nginx. Then I used that log snippet to create a policy module with audit2allow and inserted the policy with `semodule -i <my_policy.pp>`.  Naturally there was more than one round of errors, so I removed the policy and repeated the process above until Nginx ran successfully. I used this iterative approach so that audit2allow wouldn't generate a policy that was any more permissive than necessary.  Does that amount to the same result you had in mind?

Comment: No, as the AVC denial message would suggest the problem was that your files were incorrectly labeled. Using `audit2allow` likely added required permissions for `httpd_t` to access/modify files with type `default_t`. Relabeling the files in `/path/to/site` with appropriate `httpd_..._t` labels would likely have solved the issue, as the rules already exist to allow access between those types.